# Unable to use Interface with CakePHP Dependency Injection - "Argument must be of type AuthorizationServiceInterface, string given"

Tags: cakephp, dependency-injection, authorization, cakephp-4.x

I want to create a service class in my app that has the `AuthorizationService` as a dependency so it can access the user’s identity. I have this constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    private readonly AuthorizationServiceInterface $authorization,
    private readonly OrganizationsTable $organizationsTable,
    private readonly array $config = []
) { ... }
```

I have an `AuthorizationServiceProvider` that I’ve registered in `Application::services()` but it actually does two jobs:

1. extends `ServiceProvider` and implements `services()`
2. implements `AuthorizationServiceProviderInterface` and implements `getAuthorizationService()`

(Technically the book says to attach the latter interface to your Application class but I broke it out into a separate class and I instantiate that class and pass it to the `AuthorizationMiddleware`. This part works fine.)

For my services method in this class I have:

```
public function services(ContainerInterface $container): void
{
    $container->add(AuthorizationServiceInterface::class, function () use ($container) {
        $request = $container->get(ServerRequestInterface::class);
        return $this->getAuthorizationService($request);
    });
}
```

So basically I’m trying to register the `AuthorizationServiceInterface` in the container then provide a concrete implementation by calling my `getAuthorizationService()` method in this same class.

Crucially, in this class I also have:

```
protected $provides = [
    AuthorizationServiceInterface::class,
];
```

However, I’m getting this error:

```
“App\\Service\\Crud\\Organization\\OrganizationSearcher::__construct(): Argument #1 ($authorization) must be of type Authorization\\AuthorizationServiceInterface, string given”
```

In the past this has always indicated (to me) that I’m missing that class FQCN in the `$provides` class property. But as you can see, it is there.

What am I doing wrong?

1. Tried ensuring the `AuthorizationServiceInterface` was present in the `$provides` class property
2. Tried clearing the cache with `bin/cake cache clear_all`
3. Tried reordering the Service Providers in `Application::services()` to see if that had any effect

Ultimately, I expect the service container to be able to resolve an `AuthorizationServiceInterface`  by using my `getAuthorizationService()` method and pass it to my service class that needs it.